# Backlight Fix in Ubuntu with MacBook 6,1?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04, brightness, macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu to dual boot on my MacBook. However, the brightness feature does not work! It only happened after I changed the display driver. I am using Ubuntu 13.04

`lspci:`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Host Bridge (rev b1)
00:00.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller (rev b1)
00:03.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 LPC Bridge (rev b3)
00:03.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller (rev b1)
00:03.2 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 SMBus (rev b1)
00:03.3 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller (rev b1)
00:03.4 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller (rev b1)
00:03.5 Co-processor: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Co-processor (rev b1)
00:04.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev b1)
00:04.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev b1)
00:06.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev b1)
00:06.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev b1)
00:08.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio (rev b1)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Bridge (rev b1)
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Ethernet (rev b1)
00:0b.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 SATA Controller (rev b1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C79 [GeForce 9400M] (rev b1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
```

`jockey-text

```
kmod:nvidia_173 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_310 - nvidia_310 (Proprietary, Enabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_310_updates - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:wl - Broadcom STA wireless driver (Proprietary, Enabled, In use) [auto-install]
kmod:nvidia_313_updates - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_304_updates - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_304 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
```

Strangely the Nvidia driver I am using is not showing up as in use from the output above. It is the `NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDAPU library from nvidia-310`

How do I fix the brightness on the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this deb:

https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/raw/master/install/deb/nvidiabl-dkms_0.81_all.deb

Load the module:

```
sudo modprobe nvidiabl
```

Paste this into your /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier     "Device0"
   Driver         "nvidia"
   VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
   Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   Option         "NoLogo" "True"
   Option         "AllowGLXWithComposite" "true"
   Option         "DPMS" "1"
   Option         "OnDemandVBlankInterrupts" "1"
   Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1; PowerMizerEnable=0x1;    PerfLevelSrc=0x2233;PowerMizerDefault=0x3"
EndSection
```

Now the brightness control should work.

Comment: That didn't work... is there any special procedure I need to follow?

Comment: Hm. not sure. I added my xorg.conf section. Maybe this helps?